# swift how to split string but contains the separators

Tags: swift

I have a string like `100 + 8 - 9 + 10`, how to get `["100", "+", "8", "-", "9", "+", "10"]` in an array.

```
let string = "100 + 8 - 9 + 10"
let splitted = string.split(omittingEmptySubsequences: true, whereSeparator: { ["+", "-"].contains(String($0)) })
```

But I got `["100", "8", "9", "10"]`, I lost `+` and `-`, any good way? Thanks!

**EDIT**
 Thanks for the comment, not guarantee about spaces. Could be  like "100+8 - 9 ".

Comment: There are spaces, so what about splitting according to a space character?

Comment: Do you guarantee that there is *always* a spaces between the values? if yes, then  you could simply separate it as: `string.components(separatedBy: " ")`

Comment: @AhmadF no,  could have spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know whether or not the string will contain spaces, you should probably use a `Scanner`

```
let string = "100 + 8 - 9 + 10"

let removed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
// "100+8-9+10"

let scanner = Scanner(string: removed)

let operators = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-*/")

var components: [String] = []

while !scanner.isAtEnd {
    var value: Int = 0
    if scanner.scanInt(&value) {
        components.append("\(value)")
    }

    var op: NSString? = ""
    if scanner.scanCharacters(from: operators, into: &op) {
        components.append(op! as String)
    }
}

print(components)

// ["100", "+", "8", "-", "9", "+", "10"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashley, seems this not work on string like `5+ (8 + 9)`, sorry didn't mention bracket. Even though I can change  `operators `to `"+-*/()"` then remove `(` and `)` in the string, or ```op.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")```? But seems not a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear from your question or comment what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to extract values and operators to use them in computation, you'll need to keep the brackets. e.g `(5+8)*9 != 5+8*9`. If you're still having problems, I suggest you ask a new question with more details about what you're actually trying to do, along with the code you have so far.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Ashley. By far you answer is correct for my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can just split your string by spaces.

```
let splitted = string.split(separator: " ")
```

The value of `splitted` is

```
["100", "+", "8", "-", "9", "+", "10"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure  about the spaces.

Comment: This was the correct answer for the original question - but unfortunately the OP changed the goalposts!